# How to use Blender for direct drawing on canvas? (in the same way as Processing)

Tags: python, scripting, compositing-nodes, grease-pencil

Is there in Blender a way of use/configuration equivalent to that offered by a drawing environment canvas-based, such as Processing, so that it draws directly to a render output without going through an object creation phase? I will try to explain myself better with an example:
The following python code for Processing IDE would paint 8 million pixels directly on a canvas, for which it does not store any object or state information, therefore it handles it in an agile and quite fast way:

```
def setup():
    size(1920, 1080)
    background(255)
    for i in range(0,8000000):
        x = random(0,1920)
        y = random(0,1080)
        
        point(x,y)
```

Equivalent code that would perform a similar composition in Blender using a Grease Pencil object could be as follows:

```
import bpy
import random

sel_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

if sel_obj.type == 'GPENCIL':
    gpencil = sel_obj.data
    gp_layer = gpencil.layers.active
    gp_frame = gp_layer.frames[0]
    
    gp_frame.clear()
    
    for i in range(0,8000000):
        gp_stroke = gp_frame.strokes.new()
        gp_stroke.line_width = 1
        gp_stroke.points.add(count=1)
        gp_stroke.points[0].co = (random.random(), 0.0,random.random())
```

The problem is that handling so many points is unassumable in Blender; in simple tests, although it manages to generate all the points, it crashes when rendering.

Maybe it's a possible use of the composition editor that I don't know much about yet...?

Thanks!